# Arrays of objects in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, object, constructor

I am new to perl and seriously finding it difficult to use its object oriented features as I come from C++,python Background.
I wanted to create a list of objects , but I dont know how to achieve this in perl. I started with an array , but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
package X;

sub new {
   .....
}


package Y;

sub new {
  .....

}

package Z;

my @object_arr = ( X::new, Y::new);

foreach $object (@object_arr) {
  $object->xyz();
}
```

This throws an error "Can't call method "xyz" without a package or object reference ". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fixed up version of your code, with comments, is:

```
package X;

# You need to return a blessed object 
sub new { 
        my $self = bless {}, "X";
        return $self;
}

# You need to define xyz before calling it
sub xyz {
        print "X";
}

package Y;

sub new {
        my $self = bless {}, "Y";
        return $self;

}


sub xyz {
        print "Y";
}

package Z;

# You need to call the new method
my @object_arr = ( X->new(), Y->new());

# Don't forget to my when defining variables (including $object)
foreach my $object (@object_arr) {
  $object->xyz();
}
```

You might also want to investigate [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose)

Comment: +1 for Moose.  Coming from a similar OO background, all I can say is I don't see why you wouldn't `use Moose`.

Comment: This will break as soon as you start deriving from class X or Y.  You should say `my $class = shift; my $self = bless {}, $class;` there in the constructors.